# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' when scraping table data

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am currently having problems understanding following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

It is referring to line 21 of the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/wetterundklima_vorort/hessen/offenbach/_node.html'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup

# obtain information from html tag <table>

table = soup.find('table', id='wetklitab')
table

# obtain information from html tag <tr>

headers = []
for i in table.find_all('tr'):
    title = i.text
    headers.append(title)
    print(f"{title}")
```

which is `for i in table.find_all('tr'):`
can somebody explain the error and how to solve it? thank you.

Comment: The error means that there is no `table` that the `soup` object finds. Are you sure the table has that exact id in the HTML page?

Comment: @AltJf, Please accept my answer if you think it solves your original problem. Thanks.

Comment: @StonedTensor The Id is stored in a div, that's probably my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from the fact that `table` is `None` after the `soup.find` line. You can confirm that by testing `table is None`, which will give you `True`. The reason is that the table you are looking for actually does not have an id. Instead, it is under a `div` tag that has such an id.

Here is a quick fix of your code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/wetterundklima_vorort/hessen/offenbach/_node.html'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup

# obtain information from html tag <table>
div_ele = soup.find('div', id='wetklitab')
table = div_ele.find('table')
table

# obtain information from html tag <tr>

headers = []
for i in table.find_all('tr'):
    title = i.text
    headers.append(title)
    print(f"{title}")
```

Comment: thank you, that helped. So the program should first search for a div containing a id and in this div it searches for tr and prints it out. got it, thank you.